# CSS selectors ul li a {...} vs ul > li > a {...}

Tags: css, css-selectors

1. What is the difference between `ul > li > a {...}` and `ul li a {...}` in CSS?
2. Which one is more efficient and why?

Comment: I assume one of those is meant to be different?

Comment: I fixed it ..that was a typo.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

"`>`" is the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)

"" is the [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors)

The difference is that a descendant can be a child of the element, or a child of a child of the element or a child of a child of a child *ad inifinitum*.

A child element is simply one that is directly contained within the parent element:

```
<foo> <!-- parent -->
  <bar> <!-- child of foo, descendant of foo -->
    <baz> <!-- descendant of foo -->
    </baz>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

for this example, `foo *` would match `<bar>` and `<baz>`, whereas `foo > *` would only match `<bar>`.

As for your second question:

> Which one is more efficient and why?

I'm not actually going to answer this question as it's completely irrelevant to development. CSS rendering engines are so fast that there is almost never* a reason to optimize CSS selectors beyond making them as short as possible.

Instead of worrying about micro-optimizations, focus on writing selectors that make sense for the case at hand. I often use `>` selectors when styling nested lists, because it's important to distinguish which level of the list is being styled.

<sub>* if it genuinely is an issue in rendering the page, you've probably got too many elements on the page, or too much CSS. Then you'll have to run some tests to see what the actual issue is.</sub>

Answer (score 20):

`ul>li` selects all `li` that are a direct child of `ul` whereas `ul li` selects all `li` that are anywhere within (descending as deep as you like) a `ul`

For HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><span><a href='#'>Something</a></span></li>
  <li><a href='#'>or Other</a></li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
li a{ color: green; }
li>a{ color: red; }
```

The colour of `Something` will remain green but `or Other` will be red

Part 2, you should write the rule to be appropriate to the situation, I think the speed difference would be incredibly small, and probably overshadowed by the extra characters involved in writing more code, and definitely overshadowed by the time taken by the developer to think about it.

However, as a rule of thumb, the more specific you are with your rules, the faster the CSS engines can locate the DOM elements you want to apply it to, so I expect `li>a` is faster than `li a` as the DOM search can be cut short earlier. It also means that nested anchors are not styled with that rule, is that what you want? <~~ much more pertinent question.

Comment: That answers the first part of the question and what about the second part ?

Comment: That's a bad example. `<span>` elements can't be children of `<ul>` elements.

Answer (score 11):

`ul > li > a` selects only the direct children. In this case only the first level `<a>` of the first level `<li>` inside the `<ul>` will be selected.

`ul li a` on the other hand will select ALL `<a>`-s in ALL `<li>`-s in the unordered list

Example of `ul > li`

```css
ul > li.bg {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="bg">affected</li>
  <li class="bg">affected</li>    
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li class="bg">NOT affected</li>
      <li class="bg">NOT affected</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

if you'd be using `ul li` - ALL of the `li`-s would be affected

**UPDATE** The order of more to less efficient CSS selectors goes thus:

- ID, e.g.`#header`
- Class, e.g. `.promo`
- Type, e.g. `div`
- Adjacent sibling, e.g. `h2 + p`
- Child, e.g. `li > ul`
- Descendant, e.g. `ul a`
- Universal, i.e. `*`
- Attribute, e.g. `[type="text"]`
- Pseudo-classes/-elements, e.g. `a:hover`

So your better bet is to use the `children` selector instead of just `descendant`. However the difference on a regular page (without tens of thousands elements to go through) might be absolutely negligible.

Comment: The implied efficiency question makes sense: given `<ul><li><a></a></li></ul>`, which selector is faster out of `ul > li > a` and `ul li a`? However, I completely agree with zzzzBov's answer to the efficiency question.

Comment: I just tried the code and the "NOT affected" parts are actually selected with "ul>li" for two reasons. 1) The inner <ul> is a <li>-element. 2) There inner list is also of the type "ul>li". The example works if the inner list is "ol" instead of "ul", and it is placed inside a div, not as a <li>-element.

Answer (score 1):

1) for example HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">firstlink</a>
        <span><a href="#">second link&lt;/a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and css rules:

```
1) ul li a {color:red;} 
2) ul > li > a {color:blue;}
```

">" - symbol mean that that will be searching only child selector (parentTag > childTag)

so first css rule will apply to all links (first and second)
and second rule will apply anly to first link

2) As for efficiency - I think second will be more fast - as in case with JavaScript selectors. This rule read from right to left, this mean that when rule will parse by browser, it get all links on page: 
- in first case it will find all parent elements for each link on page and filter all links where exist parent  tags "ul" and "li"
- in second case it will check only parent node of link if it is  "li" tag then -> check if parent tag of "li" is "ul"

some thing like this.
Hope I describe all properly for you

Answer (score 1):

Here `> a` to specifiy the color for root of `li.active.menu-item`

#primary-menu > li.active.menu-item > a

```css
#primary-menu>li.active.menu-item>a {
  color: #c19b66;
}
```

```html
<ul id="primary-menu">
  <li class="active menu-item"><a>Coffee</a>
    <ul id="sub-menu">
      <li class="active menu-item"><a>aaa</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a>bbb</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a>ccc</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="menu-item"><a>Tea</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a>Coca Cola</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

to answer to your second question - performance IS affected - if you are using those selectors with a single (no nested) ul:

```
<ul>
    <li>jjj</li>
    <li>jjj</li>    
    <li>jjj</li>
</ul>
```

the child selector `ul > li` is more performant than `ul li` because it is more specific. the browser traverse the dom "right to left", so when it finds a `li` it then looks for a any `ul` as a parent in the case of a child selector, while it has to traverse the whole dom tree to find any `ul` ancestors in case of the descendant selector

Comment: erg typo - it's the opposite because child selector is more specific - well spotted! - answer now updated

Comment: I think you are wrong .....going by answers above ul > li should be more efficient than  ul li since the css engine doesn't have to go through a whole bunch of ancestors to find a match

Comment: @Subhra yes I made a typo in my answer - I've amended it a while ago.