# difference in css styling between <ul> > <li> and <ul> <li>

Tags: html, css

What is the difference in css styling between `divClass > ul > li > a` and `divClass ul li a` basically I am trying to style an anchor tag which is in li and li belongs to ul of course and ul is inside a div and div class name is classDiv, I have done some basic research and I have tried in both ways but not working yet, here is html

```
<div class="classDiv">            
        <ul>                
            <li class="abc">google.com</li>                
        </ul>                            
    </div>
```

and css

```
.classDiv > ul > li > a:hover{    
color: green;
background-color: skyblue;
cursor: pointer;    
}
```

Comment: do your html has a `<a href=""></a>` tag? it should be like this `<li class="abc"><a href="">google.com</a></li>`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks even the most fundamental research. Asking Google once resolves the question.

Comment: as i said i have tried different ways but still not working, and I am not so much familiar with these things

Comment: Anchor tag, is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```css
    .classDiv > ul > li > a:hover {
      color: green;
      background-color: skyblue;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<div class="classDiv">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="www.google.com">Google.com</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you have no anchor tag in your code and your css is mentioning `a:hover` so how the style will be applied @mohsin

Comment: by mistake i foget to put anchor in here at site, but any way the problum was that , I was putting the text google.com inside <li><a></a>google.com</li> any way thanks very much but the last thing pls explain the difference between   .classDiv > ul > li > a:hover  and .classDiv  ul li  a:hover

Comment: @mohsin the main difference is that `>` points that the tag inside like `ul > li > a` means it applys style for anchor tag only and `ul li a` means it applies style for all tags `ul li a`

Answer (score 3):

"`>`" is the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)

"" is the [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors)

The difference is that a descendant can be a child of the element, or a child of a child of the element or a child of a child of a child ad inifinitum.

A child element is simply one that is directly contained within the parent element:

```
<foo> <!-- parent -->
  <bar> <!-- child of foo, descendant of foo -->
    <baz> <!-- descendant of foo -->
    </baz>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

for this example, `foo *` would match `<bar>` and `<baz>`, whereas `foo > *` would only match `<bar>`. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227322/css-selectors-ul-li-a-vs-ul-li-a)

Comment: You should not reward people that refuse to do the most basic research.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*you can try this is also working */
        <div class="classDiv">            
                <ul>                
                    <li class="abc"><a href="#">google.com</a></li>                
                </ul>                            
            </div>

    .classDiv li a{    
    color: white;
    background-color: skyblue;
    cursor: pointer;    
    }

    .classDiv li a:hover{    
    color: green;
    background-color: skyblue;
    cursor: pointer;    
    }
```